# 'while' loop in string compare function loops more than necessary

Tags: c

The strcmp_kr function is based on the string compare function from K&R.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int strcmp_kr (char *s, char *d) {

int i=0;

    while ((s[i] == d[i])) {
        printf("Entered while loop\n");
        if (s[i] == '\0')
            return 0;
        i++;
    }
    return s[i] - d[i];
}

int main() {

char s1[15];
char s2[15];
printf("Enter string no. 1:");
scanf("%s", s1);
printf("Enter string no. 2:");
scanf("%s", s2);
strcmp_kr(s1, s2) == 0 ? printf("Strings equal!\n") : \
printf("Strings not equal by %d!\n", strcmp_kr(s1, s2));
```

}

Output:

$ ./a.out

Enter string no. 1:modest

Enter string no. 2:modesy

Entered while loop

Entered while loop

Entered while loop

Entered while loop

Entered while loop

Entered while loop

Entered while loop

Entered while loop

Entered while loop

Entered while loop

Strings not equal by -5!

Question:
Why is the while loop entering 10 times instead of 5?

Comment: Do not use `scanf()` without specifying field width otherwise it has a risk of buffer overrun, it doesn't exactly concern your problem though. I mentioned it as a precaution :)

Answer (score 8):

```
strcmp_kr(s1, s2) == 0 ? printf("Strings equal!\n") : \
printf("Strings not equal by %d!\n", strcmp_kr(s1, s2));
```

you have called `strcmp_kr(s1, s2)` twice ,first in the condition, and second in the `printf` since your condition is `false`, so you get 10 times of the print message.

to avoid this, store the return value in a variable like

```
int rtn = strcmp_kr(s1, s2);
rtn == 0 ? printf("Strings equal!\n") : \
printf("Strings not equal by %d!\n", rtn);
```

Answer (score 2):

you're calling the function twice:

**strcmp_kr(s1, s2)** == 0 ? printf("Strings equal!\n") : \
printf("Strings not equal by %d!\n", **strcmp_kr(s1, s2))**;

The first call evaluates to false and calls the function again.

Cheers!